# using jquery append() to add a button to a form

Tags: jquery, forms, append

I need to add a button to a form.  I have no control over the logic that creates the form itself... but i can add code around the form, if need be.

The code for the form looks like this:

```
<form action="/cgi-bin/a/logon" method="POST">
     <DT>Login ID</DT>
       <DD>
          <input class=" text" type="text"  name="id"  value="">
       </DD>
     <DT>Password</DT>
       <DD>
          <input class=" password" type="password"  name="password"  value="">
       </DD>
       <DT></DT>
       <DD><input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Logon">
      </DD>
</FORM>
```

I know I can add a div around the entire form and append to that... but I would like the new button to appear right beside the "Logon" button.
I've tried the following code, but it didn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $('.submit').append($('<input type="button" value="test">'));
        });
</script>
```

I'm assuming you probably can't append to a button... which is why it didn't work.

I'm still learning jquery so if there's another method aside from append that I could use, I'm all ears!  Actually, the button doesn't have to be a part of the form because I'm going to run client side code when it is clicked.  But it does have to appear beside the login button.

Thanks.

Comment: Note, `name="submit"` should be avoided, it can interfere with the form's submit method if called directly (such as `form.submit()`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you cannot **append anything to the input** element ..

Use `.after` or `.before`

```
 $('.submit').after($('<input type="button" value="test">'));
```

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't create any button.  I am checking F12 in firefox... under console, I don't see any errors.  Neither in script

Comment: actually, never mind. I found the error.  missing ); it works!

Answer (score 2):

try this instead: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/justincook/Yg8rj/)

```
$('<input type="button" value="test">').insertAfter('.submit');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.after` like this

```
$('.submit').after('<input type="button" value="test" />');
```

OR

```
$('form').append('<input type="button" value="test" />');
```